# Spring security multiple logout urls?

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring security java config and I wanted to know a way to implemented log-out for multiple urls. i.e.

```
logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new 
AntPathRequestMatcher("/invalidate")).logoutUrl("/logout");
```

In this code the normal logout url "/logout" works fine and its a post request but i also want the user to logout for the url "/invalidate" which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I am trying to understand business use case of your need.

Comment: there is a legacy url in the application that should logout users (get request) and the normal post logout should keep working as well

Comment: anyone knows anything about it?

Comment: Would like to know as well.

Comment: One thing, your call to `.logoutUrl("/logout")` overrides the previously set `/invalidate` path.

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring Security tutorial, it seems that the next is more elegant approach:

[image]

In the security form-login tag just add something like this:

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler"/>
```

Every time that you'll hit /logout URL the `logoutHandler` will be invoked, and on it, you can decide how to behave after a successful logout.

From Spring docs:

[image]

All you need to do is to create a new class that implements the interface marked in the image and implement its single method.

On that method decide how to act after a successful logout. for example:

```
@Component("logoutHandler")
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(request.getParameter("msgShow") != null && request.getParameter("msgShow").equals("false")){
            redirectResponse(request, response, "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + "/my_web_app/home?logout=false");
        }
        else{
            redirectResponse(request, response,"http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + "/my_web_app/home?logout=true");
        }
    }

    private void redirectResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String destination) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader("Location", destination);
    }
}
```

Now don't forget to add a `@Component` annotation to the above logout handler + on security configuration file add the next 2 statements:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="package.to.logout.handler" />
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant way, but you can just specify a @Controller that is mapped to all the URLs you want for logout, e. g.

```
@Controller
public class LogoutController {

  final String logoutRedirectUrl = "redirect:http://yourredirect.xy";

  @RequestMapping("/logout")
  public String logout1(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    request.logout();
    return logoutRedirectUrl;
  }    

  @RequestMapping("/second/logout/")
  public String logout2(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    request.logout();
    return logoutRedirectUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that additional logout URL should be specified in the security configuration file.

Comment: Tarun Sapra wanted to know how to specify two URLs for logout, not one logout URL that does two things. As far as I know, you can only specify one URL in the security config file. The solution I proposed provides a solution, while the one @Moshe Arad presented does something different (though definitely more elegantly)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip, the actual matching should be improved.

```
List logoutUrls = Arrays.asList(
    "/rest/logout1",
    "/rest/logout2"
);
RequestMatcher rm = new RequestMatcher() {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String uriStr = request.getRequestURI().toString();
    return logoutUrls.stream()
        .filter(lu -> uriStr.contains(lu))
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();
  }
};
```

and then register the request matcher:

```
http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutRequestMatcher(rm));
```